# More UX design questions relating to different languages/cultures

Tags: discussion, tags, culture

How can we encourage more discussion about inclusive design, especially taking into account of catering for different languages and cultures?

I saw some UI design questions that show screen shots of languages other than English. Should we be tagging these to their respective country/language to try and encourage more people to submit questions specific to these country/language?

Comment: We do have tags for Localization and internationalization which should be applied as relevant, though just because a question has screenshots with a different language it doesn't necessarily mean language or localization is a relevant part of the question. Not really a fan of tagging languages just because they're used. Just because my form's in Japanese doesn't mean my Q isn't just about checkboxes.

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree with most of your points, but I did notice that some of the questions on UX StackExchange dealing with different languages and cultures didn't get a lot of answers, so I am wonder if it is to do with the way people ask the questions or it is just an area not really given to too much thought in UX design...